# Objetos en Android no aparecen en lugar

Tags: java, android, xml

Vengo de hace algún tiempo de java, pero me vi en la necesidad de hacer una aplicación en Android. El caso, que cuando compilo mi programa con el simulador de Android Studio, las cosas aparecen agapiñadas en la esquina superior izquierda. Busqué por todo internet, y no encontré solución que me valiera. Adjunto código XML de la visualización y el código en Java por si es necesario.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="Iteraciones"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="154dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv4"
    android:layout_width="137dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="179dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv5"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="249dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="153dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:text="Número de Iteraciones:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="153dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:text="Número a Computar:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="139dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="179dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="compute"
    android:text="Computar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="40dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="105dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
package luiss.collatz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et1;
private TextView tv4,tv5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv5);
}

public void compute(View view) {
    String ns = et1.getText().toString();
    int n = Integer.parseInt(ns);
    int i = 0;
    int x = n;
    String[] a = new String[200];
    String f;
    while (x > 1) {

        if(x % 2 == 0){
            x = x/2;
        }
        else {
            x = (3*x)+1;
        }

        System.out.println(x);

        a[i] = (""+x);

        i++;

    }
    f = String.join(", ", a);
    tv4.setText(""+i);
    tv5.setText(""+n+", "+f);
    }
 }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías adjuntar imagen del emulador? para ver el problema...

Comment: Viendo tu xml en android studio lanza el error "missing constraints in ConstraintLayout" debes agregar los constraint a las views, en este video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf3_NqnG7bM](http://Viendo%20tu%20xml%20en%20android%20studio%20lanza%20el%20error%20%22missing%20constraints%20in%20ConstraintLayout%22,%20este%20video%20explica%20como%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf3_NqnG7bM) puedes ver como se usa ConstraintLayout. Saludos

Comment: Viendo tu xml en android studio lanza el error "missing constraints in ConstraintLayout" debes agregar los constraint a las views, en este video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf3_NqnG7bM](http://Viendo%20tu%20xml%20en%20android%20studio%20lanza%20el%20error%20%22missing%20constraints%20in%20ConstraintLayout%22,%20este%20video%20explica%20como%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf3_NqnG7bM) puedes ver como se usa ConstraintLayout. Saludos

Comment: En el sitio puedes encontrar informacioón de esto: @LuisSolana https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+constraintlayout

Answer (score 0):

Tu layout no esta restringido (Constraint), cuando lo esta, en la ventana de texto se vería algo así:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tx5"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="249dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv4" />
```

Hay que hacer click en los círculos superiores y laterales y arrastralos.En la ventana de diseño se ve así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando no lo esta, por ejemplo `TextView` esta subrayado en rojo, se vería así:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tx5"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="249dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp" />
```

Y en la ventana de diseño, se vería así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]